# vSphere and ESX License questions

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

We currently have a ESX Environment  which has 1x Physical vSphere Server, 1x SAN (Another coming soon) 2x ESXi Hosts.

We currently have licensing for vSphere and ESX Essentials.

I need to add 2 more ESX Hosts and I know in Essentials / Essentials Plus there is a Max limit of 3 physical hosts.

I need to find out which version would be able to allow me to run vSphere server with 4x ESX Hosts. I have tried to find out for Standard Edition but a straight forward answer to this has alluded me and my Google searches. Are any of you able to help on this matter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Only vCenter Essentials has a host limitation. You will have to license on a per-CPU basis.